# Is there powdered blood in TANG-pineapple powdered juice mix?

Tags: safety, food-chemistry

My TANG pineapple juice drink mix is a yellow powder. When I add a little water to it, it dissolves and red dots are briefly observed before mixing with the yellow dots is complete, after which time the red dots disappear.

What happened? I'm scared: are the red dots from powdered blood?

Comment: What?? Why would you suspect blood?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not really about chemistry.

Answer (score 3):

I think this question might be slightly off-topic...  but in case you are really concerned, I think the answer is no.

What you might be seeing is an effect of the Tang powder getting wet before it dissolves fully to form your Tang drink.  [See this post from the physics Stack Exchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/30366/why-wet-is-dark) or [this post from 'Ask the Van' at the University of Illinois](https://van.physics.illinois.edu/qa/listing.php?id=21080)

Things appear to be darker when they are wet, for reasons explained in the posts I linked to (briefly, dry objects reflect more light than wet ones, as the water allows more light to pass through a wet object).  So your yellow powder might be appearing as a darker shade of orange, the 'red spots' you see.

Also, if Tang were really putting blood in its drinks, various food standards regulatory bodies would probably notice and stop them from doing it, and there would have to be court cases etc.  So keep drinking the Kool aid (or whichever brand you prefer)!